# SDL, OpenGL: Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, sdl-image

When I try generate texture with openGL I get a segmentation fault in this method:

```
 void RendererGL::create_gl(SDL_Surface * surf, GLuint * tex ) {
   GLenum format;   GLint  colors_amount = surf->format->BytesPerPixel;

   if (colors_amount == 4) {
           if (surf->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
                   format = GL_RGBA;
           else
                   format = GL_BGRA;
   }
   else if (colors_amount == 3) {
           if (surf->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
                   format = GL_RGB;
           else
                   format = GL_BGR;
   }
   else {
       gCritical("Image is not truecolor");
   }
   glGenTextures( 1, tex );

   glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, *tex );

   glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
   glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

   glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, colors_amount, surf->w, surf->h, 0, format,
                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surf->pixels ); }
```

I`ve this problem only on debian with nvidia drivers. With open sources driver application run properly. Valgrind test return:

```
[ Info ] RendererGL::Init GL
==13033== Thread 3:
==13033== Invalid read of size 8
==13033==    at 0x51293C9: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/current/libGL.so.304.64)
==13033==    by 0x419B0F: RendererGL::initGL() (RendererGL.cpp:12)
==13033==    by 0x41036C: Renderer::Renderer() (Renderer.cpp:27)
==13033==    by 0x4058EA: Renderer::getInstance() (Renderer.hpp:17)
==13033==    by 0x40B648: StandardReferences::StandardReferences() (StandardReferences.hpp:13)
==13033==    by 0x414C26: Map::Map(short**, unsigned short, unsigned int, unsigned int) (Map.cpp:8)
==13033==    by 0x4136E4: MapManager::loadMapFromFile(std::string, short) (MapManager.cpp:82)
==13033==    by 0x4138A0: MapManager::load() (MapManager.cpp:97)
==13033==    by 0x4084BA: Resource::load() (Resource.cpp:36)
==13033==    by 0x4196AF: Splash::initThread(void*) (Splash.cpp:99)
==13033==    by 0x53D0405: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4)
==13033==    by 0x5413898: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4)
==13033==  Address 0x658 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==13033== 
==13033== 
==13033== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13033==     in use at exit: 22,104,451 bytes in 31,729 blocks
==13033==   total heap usage: 47,499 allocs, 15,770 frees, 54,869,707 bytes allocated
==13033== 
==13033== LEAK SUMMARY:
==13033==    definitely lost: 833 bytes in 8 blocks
==13033==    indirectly lost: 1,728 bytes in 38 blocks
==13033==      possibly lost: 269,732 bytes in 99 blocks
==13033==    still reachable: 21,832,158 bytes in 31,584 blocks
==13033==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13033== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==13033== 
==13033== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==13033== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==13033== ERROR SUMMARY: 12 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

Comment: The third parameter of glTexImage2D, which you feed by a variable "color_amount" doesn not take arbitrary values. By specification it must be one of the format tokens as found in the glTexImage2D reference; however using an invalid token should not cause a segfault.

Comment: Try adding this to the very start of your main: `setenv( "MESA_DEBUG", "", 0 );`. It will enable debugging/warning messages from Mesa/OpenGL (it writes them to stdout/stderr). I usually just wrap it in `#ifdef DEBUG` and have it in every GL program.

Comment: The only thing I could think of is that your texture might have non-power-of-two dimensions, and your nvidia card doesn't support it. I'm just guessing though.

Comment: Thanks for reply :) My image have size: 2048x1024 px, and I don`t think that this is problem. I getting segm failed in this line: glGenTextures( 1, tex );

GDB session end with this:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. [Switching to Thread 0x7fffe85f2700 (LWP 3888)] 0x00007ffff7db91a9 in glGenTextures () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (gdb) next Single stepping until exit from function glGenTextures, which has no line number information. 0x00007ffff75c3e40 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL-1.2.so.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm bettin' it's segfaulting with RGB surfaces but not RGBA ones.

Try [`glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)​`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Texture_upload_and_pixel_reads) before your `glTexImage2D()` call.

`GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` defaults to 4 which works fine for RGBA data but will cause OpenGL to read off the end of `surf->pixels` for a RGB surface.

You'll have to use [`GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH​`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glPixelStore#Description) if `surf->pitch` is non-zero.